# "Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double' and 'String'"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

*Here is my code where it is giving me the Error, it's a timer and I am using a search bar to Change how long the timer runs and it is giving me an Error.
The brewRegularSBox is my search text field and it's giving me the error and it highlights the two == signs.*

```
@IBAction func startButtonDecaf(_ sender: UIButton) {
    regularStartBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    let currentDateTime = Date()
   let formatter = DateFormatter()
   formatter.timeStyle = .short
   let dateTimeString = formatter.string(from: currentDateTime)
    regularStartBtn.setTitle(dateTimeString, for: .normal)
   
  
    timer3 = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60.0, target: self, selector: #selector(UIOutlitsViewController.action1), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func action() {
    time1 += 1
    timeView1.text = String(time1)
    if time1 == brewRegularSBox.text! {     This is the error "Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double' and 'String' "   
       

 btnPressed1.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red
        
         btnPressed1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        btnPressed1.setTitle("Check", for: .normal)
        
        
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "mixkit-alarm-clock-beep-988", withExtension: "wav")
        player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
        player.play()
        player.numberOfLoops = 16
        timer3.invalidate()
        
    }
}
```

Comment: How would suggest comparing a numerical value to a `String` should work?  Based on the limit context, I might suggest doing `if timeView1.text == brewRegularSBox.text { ... }` instead, but it both are `nil`, this will also be equal, so something like `if let lhs = timeView1.text, let rhs = brewRegularSBox.text, lhs == rhs { ... }` might be better, but, we're missing a lot of context

Comment: It now gives me a Error that says "Expected expression after unary operator" and it underlines the { ...} part

Comment: ... You didn't put the `...` in as well did you?

Comment: I did........ what should I put

Comment: `...` means "your code goes here"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing  `brewRegularSBox.text` to `Double(brewRegularSBox.text)`

you cant compare numbers and a string of text.  :)

Comment: `text` property is optional

Comment: I tried that now it gives me this Error "No exact matches in call to initializer"

Comment: @kaleb `Double(brewRegularSBox.text!)`